# What in this world am I?

Tags: riddle

> - I don't live but all life has me.
> - It ain't easy to destroy me, but if you do, I'll destroy you.
> - You won't see me as me.
> - My sibling is known as tekahaamandlakusogzogikethamopolmphamvu

And..

> My name is a tiny little word

Also..

> I am not oxygen

I wasn't able to make a proper rhyme out of these, so any edits for it are always welcome.

Comment: my rhyming dictionary doesn't have tekahaamandlakusogzogikethamopolmphamvu, not sure why they left that one out :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer

> Instead of energy, you are mass.

Reasons

> It doesn’t live, but all life has it.
>
> It is very hard to turn mass into our energy, or to “destroy” it. If that happens, massive amounts of energy are released. For a classic example, think of nuclear bombs.)
>
> “Mass” is a tiny word, and mass itself is very small. In addition, oxygen is made of mass.
>
> Finally, as the below answer states, “According to Google Translate, 'tekahaamandlakusogzogikethamopolmphamvu' is Zulu for energy efficiency.” Mass but not the sibling to energy! After all, think of Einstien's famous e=mc2!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it is

> Energy

Because

> Everything has energy, but you aren't alive
>  The Law of Conservation of Energy states that you cannot destroy it
>  You can't see energy, only the effects it has on other objects
>  According to Google Translate, 'tekahaamandlakusogzogikethamopolmphamvu' is Zulu for energy efficiency

Comment: You are close, but this is not the answer. Also try translating energy efficiency from English to Zulu. I don't know why it is showing energy efficient as the translation to this text (maybe Google looks for just a few words, considers the closest match), but it isn't.